# Way to merge files from base xcode project to child xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, merge

I am having a base xcode project(say ABC). I copied all files from ABC project into other xcode project(say XYZ). Both are independent projects. 
Now my problem is that I did a lots of changes in both projects, changes took place in same file also. How can I merge code from base project,ABC, to other project,XYZ. I don't want to merge all files one by one (manually) to merge changes. 
Is there any automated tool or script which merge all files.  OR 
Way which compares both projects and give me list of conflict files.

Comment: Hi. Are you use a source control system?

Comment: Yes.. I am using git for it.

Comment: So, what is the problem? Just use the `Git` common functionality for merging.

Comment: I used it but it is not working.